# text on the top of page

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, tikz-node, fill

i tried to add a box on the top of page with tikz package but i didn't add a text as it is shown in the figure.
[image]
this is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[fill=rougeECL] (0,0) rectangle
    (\paperwidth,1cm);%{\color{white} AU:2020-2022};
  \node[yshift=15, xshift=0.67\paperwidth,rectangle,
         rounded corners=27pt,inner sep=11pt,
         fill=rougeECL]
        {\color{white} \shortstack{Code ECUE :\\ GCR.P2.5.1.27.2.F}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), I didn't look for any particular geometry of your page.

You can achieve what you're asking by adding another node with the same `yshift` and a different `xshift`:

[image: text on top of the page]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill=red!50!black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);
      \node[yshift=15, xshift=0.1\paperwidth,text=white]{AU:2020-2022};
      \node[yshift=15, xshift=0.67\paperwidth,
             rounded corners=27pt,
             inner sep=11pt,
             fill=red!50!black,
             text=white]
            {\shortstack{Code ECUE :\\ GCR.P2.5.1.27.2.F}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  
\end{document}
```